# Change from Index.html to Index.html#home

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sending someone a draft of a website I'm creating. However, the way how the website is designed, the Home screen is a 'a href' link which is "#home". When I'm opening the website from my computer it goes to ...../Index.html but I need it to go to ..../Index.html#home on page load. How would this be possible?

Comment: `if(!location.hash) location.hash="#home";`

Answer (score 3):

Use this script in the script section

```
window.onload = function (event) { window.location.hash = "#home"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a simple if statement:

```
document.onload = function(){
    if(!window.location.hash){
          window.location.hash="#home";
    }
}
```